# ASP.net passing data between pages

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a .aspx web page, with a html form within it, this also has two input boxes.

Whats the best way to take the input box data and pass it to a new .aspx page where it is dealt with by the request method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data is not sensitive then the best method to pass it to your new page using [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and the querystring using:

```
protected void MyFormSubmitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value1 = txtValue1.Text;
    string value2 = txtValue2.Text;

    // create a querystring
    string queryString = "x=" + value1 + "&y=" + value2;

    // redirect to the encoded querystring
    Response.Redirect("NewPage.aspx?" + Server.URLEncode(queryString));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w.aspx):

> Terminates execution of the current
>   page and starts execution of a new
>   page by using the specified URL path
>   of the page. Specifies whether to
>   clear the QueryString and Form
>   collections.
>   If you set the preserveForm parameter
>   to true, the target page will be able
>   to access the view state of the
>   previous page by using the
>   PreviousPage property.

Your main page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       // ThreadAbortException occurs here.
       // See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629 for more details.
       Server.Transfer("AnotherPage.aspx", true);  
    }
}
```

"AnotherPage.aspx":

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PreviousPage != null) 
    {
        // Accessing previous page's controls
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This web page has a lot of information which you can use for passing the values from page to page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx#Y1100